# Kong - How to associate an api with a specific jwt consumer

Tags: rest, kong

We have Kong API gateway with JWT authentication enabled. We defined two consumers. we would like to limit access to some set of our apis to a one of these consumers.  How can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. it is simply to use the kong ACL plugin.